# How to successfully use validate_token in the devise_token_auth gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

I am fairly new to Ruby and Rails itself and I'm trying to build a simple Rails API.

I want to authenticate users via token and I am therefore using the devise_token_auth gem.

I can successfully make a POST request at /auth/sign_in and I am now trying to make a GET request at /auth/validate_token

What I have, as a "test":

```
    uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in")
    response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"email" => params[:session][:email], "password" => params[:session][:password]})

    uri2 = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/auth/validate_token")
    params = { :auth_token => response['access-token'], :uid => response['uid'], :client => response['client'] }
    uri2.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
    response2 = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri2)
```

I am therefore using the access-token and uid retrieved from the response header but I keep getting a 401 response code from /auth/validate_token:

```
 Started GET "/auth/validate_token?auth_token=EEV40VDHfOaWtBzv3bn_DQ&uid=username%40example.com&client=NAzWNJalYBJLRni9dCGxXA" for ::1 at 2016-06-22 15:22:35 +0100
 Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::TokenValidationsController#validate_token as */*
   Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"EEV40VDHfOaWtBzv3bn_DQ", "uid"=>"username@example.com", "client"=>"NAzWNJalYBJLRni9dCGxXA"}
 Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is twofold:

- you send the authentication credentials as headers to the /validate_token endpoint
- you send the token header as `access-token` instead of `auth_token`

You can read about it in [this github issue](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/148). It may not have been at the time of your problem, but it is currently published in the [README](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#token-header-format).

Here are all the headers necessary for a valid authenticated request (at the time of this writing):

`"access-token": "wwwww",
"token-type":   "Bearer",
"client":       "xxxxx",
"expiry":       "yyyyy",
"uid":          "zzzzz"`

Note: these are not necessary for *every* endpoint, but usually `access-token`, `client`, and `uid` are.